# Is there any statement of Adi Shankaracharya saying that Jiva can never become Brahman?

Tags: advaita, brahman, brahma-sutras, jiva

Till now, I use to believe that Advaitha always says that Jiva can become Brahman.

But recently I heard that Adi Shankaracharya contradicted it.

Is it true? Did Adi Shankara contradicted the statement that Jiva can become Brahman?

Comment: no, he did not.

Answer (score 5):

Shankaracharya said in the  [20th verse of Brahmajnanavalimala](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/brahmajna.html?lang=sa)

ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या जीवो ब्रह्मैव नापरः ।
अनेन वेद्यं सच्छास्त्रमिति वेदान्तडिण्डिमः ॥ २०॥

Brahma Satyam Jagan Mithya Jivo Brahmaiva Na Aparah

Brahman (the Absolute) is alone real; the world is unreal; Jiva is non-different from Brahman.

The confusion comes from saying Jiva (actually Atman in this context) becomes Brahman. Shankara never said Atman becomes or does not become Brahman.This is because it already is That.